# How to align signup-form elements position to left and divide form with horizontal line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
body {
  font: 100%/1.414 "Open Sans", "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

a,
[type=submit] {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}

.signup__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1875rem 0.4375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.signup__overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.container__child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.signup__thumbnail {
  position:relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.thumbnail__logo,
.thumbnail__content,
.thumbnail__links {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumbnail__logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.logo__shape {
  fill: #fff;
}

.logo__text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.thumbnail__content {
  align-self:flex-end;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
}

.heading--primary {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.heading--secondary {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.thumbnail__links {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail__links a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.thumbnail__links a:focus, .thumbnail__links a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.signup__form {
  padding: 2.5rem;
  background: #fafafa;
}

label {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ccc;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 111;
  border-right:111;
  border-left: 111;
  border-radius: 2;
  left: 222%;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #111;
}

[type=text] {
  color: #111;
}

[type=password] {
  color: #111;
}

.btn--form {
  padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
  border-radius: 2.1875rem;
}
.btn--form:focus, .btn--form:hover {
  background: #323232;
}


.vr {
  width: 2px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color:#000;
  border: .0625rem solid #ccc;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sunrise-Spa</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body> 
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="signup__container">
  <div class="container__child signup__thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail__logo">
      
      <h1 class="logo__text">Enterprise Registration</h1>  
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail__content text-center">
      <h1 class="heading--primary">Need Help.</h1>
      <h2 class="heading--secondary">callfor 22222222 for assistance</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="signup__overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="container__child signup__form">  
    <form action="#">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="********" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="passwordRepeat" id="passwordRepeat" placeholder="********" required />
      </div>
      <div class="m-t-lg">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li>
            <input class="btn btn--form" type="submit" value="PROCEED" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have divided the Signup form into two parts, left part is for displaying some content and right side is for displaying Signup form elements like Username, email, password and repeat password.

Now i want to move the signup form elements to little bit left. and at the same time need to display the horizontal line in between two sides.

Tried Creating all but having issue with(CSS PART) moving the signup form elements to little bit left. and at the same time need to display the horizontal line in between two sides.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these code

```css
body {
  font: 100%/1.414 "Open Sans", "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

a,
[type=submit] {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}

.signup__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1875rem 0.4375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.signup__overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.container__child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.signup__thumbnail {
  position:relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.thumbnail__logo,
.thumbnail__content,
.thumbnail__links {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumbnail__logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.logo__shape {
  fill: #fff;
}

.logo__text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.thumbnail__content {
  align-self:flex-end;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
}

.heading--primary {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.heading--secondary {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.thumbnail__links {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail__links a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.thumbnail__links a:focus, .thumbnail__links a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.signup__form {
    padding: 2.5rem 2rem 2.5rem 3rem;
    background: #fafafa;
}

label {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ccc;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 111;
  border-right:111;
  border-left: 111;
  border-radius: 2;
  left: 222%;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #111;
}

[type=text] {
  color: #111;
}

[type=password] {
  color: #111;
}

.btn--form {
  padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
  border-radius: 2.1875rem;
}
.btn--form:focus, .btn--form:hover {
  background: #323232;
}


.vr {
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border: .0625rem solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sunrise-Spa</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body> 
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="signup__container">
  <div class="container__child signup__thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail__logo">
      
      <h1 class="logo__text">Enterprise Registration</h1>  
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail__content text-center">
      <h1 class="heading--primary">Need Help.</h1>
      <h2 class="heading--secondary">callfor 22222222 for assistance</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="signup__overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="container__child signup__form">  
    <form action="#">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="********" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="passwordRepeat" id="passwordRepeat" placeholder="********" required />
      </div>
      <div class="m-t-lg">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li>
            <input class="btn btn--form" type="submit" value="PROCEED" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how to divide 25% for content. and signup form elements for 75% portion with the horizontal line